# How can I efficiently make changes to a large module without having to re-run every time?

Tags: python, efficiency

When making changes to larger modules in Python, this is my current (inefficient) process:

1. Make needed change to code
2. Run program to test (using pdb - `python3 -m pdb path/to/script.py`
3. Program will throw an error
4. Fix error/create an exception
5. Run again
6. New error appears
7. Rinse an repeat

The data processing module I'm working on has many steps, and rerunning every time I make a code change to make sure there are no errors takes a long time and it's frustating. It's also obviously an inefficient way to develop a program, but I don't know what alternative

What advice do you have so that I don't have to run, and wait for, my whole data processing pipeline to find what the next error will be? Is there any way to make changes on the code and continue executing before the last error appeared? I'm a junior data person working mostly on Python and pandas.

Answer (score 4):

## Divide and Conquor

This large module can probably be broken down into smaller more easily tested functions.

Those functions probably do not provide end user behaviour, but you can at least nail down their input/output sets.

As for integration, you should still have those module level tests, and they will reveal issues. When they do take the opportunity to specify a smaller test that reveals the flaw. now you can run a faster targeted test.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is writing *[decoupled / testable code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)* through abstractions.

If you have objects, make them deal with only one *topic / level of abstraction* (*Single Responsibility Principle*). Typical examples for this are `Readers` or `Writers`. As the name suggests, they are dealing with either *reading* or *writing*. If you have different destinations to write to, use another abstraction e.g. `FileWriter`or `DBWriter`. So you could use a general `Writer`and pass the concrete *writer* as a parameter ([dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) aside: you do not need a framework to do this) in the constructor of your object.

The same goes for functions. Every external entity a function needs to work should be passed in as a parameter.

If you apply the decoupling process to your whole architecture, you end up with a layered or so called [hexagonal architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexagonal_architecture_(software)).

This allows you to easily swap out parts.

Then you could leverage a testing framework, e.g. [Pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/), to write testing code which focusses on small testable chunks of your whole codebase. You would prepare the chunk of code with enough context to make it work and produce testable (e.g. answering simple `true` `false` questions) results.

As a reading tip I recommend [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) from Robert C. Martin.
Although it has not Python as a working language, the topics are fairly language neutral - at least if you stay in the OOP-paradigm, you get the most out of it.